# Gitlab CI/CD unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from

Tags: gitlab, webdriver-io, cicd

I run tests on gitlab and it results in error. How do I fix it? What is exactly the problem?

```
ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.146)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (/builds/project/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:121:10)
    at Request._callback (/builds/project/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:121:64)
    at Request.self.callback (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

The tests are written with WebdriverIO framework with Javascript, Cucumber is also added to the project. Set up uses Node js of version 12.22 and it was built in sync mode.  I do not have this issue locally

Git-ci.yml file details are

```yaml
image: node:12.22

before_script:
  - node -v

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - test-automation
  - allure
  - deploy

e2e:chrome: &e2e
  stage: test-automation
  image: timbru31/java-node:11-jre-erbium
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run ci-stg
```

config file details are:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require('custom-env').env('stg');
const i18n = require("i18n");
const dynamicConfig = {};

if(process.env.CI_JOB_NAME) {
  dynamicConfig.capabilities = [
    { browserName: process.env.CI_JOB_NAME === 'e2e:chrome' ? 'chrome' : 'firefox' },
  ];
}

exports.config = Object.assign({}, {

  runner: 'local',
 

  suites: {
    features
  },
  specFileRetries: 0,
  specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
  specFileRetriesDeferred: true,
  maxInstances: 1,
  maxInstancesPerCapability:1,
  sync: true,
  bail: 0,
  coloredLogs: true,
  screenshotPath: './test/reports/screenShots/currentRun/errorShots/',
  waitforTimeout: 20000,
  waitforInterval: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 45000,
  connectionRetryCount: 0,
  deprecationWarnings: false,

  capabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "args": ['--headless', '--disable-gpu','--timeout=300000']
      }
    },
  ],

  baseUrl: {URL}

  cucumberOpts: {
    requireModule: ['@babel/register'],
    require: ['./test/step_definitions/**/*.js'],   // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
    backtrace: true,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    compiler: [],       // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    failFast: true,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    colors: true,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
    snippets: false,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    source: false,       // <boolean> hide source uris
    profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    strict: false,      // <booçlean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    tagExpression: '@regression and not @wip and not @defect',
    timeout: 600000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: true, // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
  },
  logLevel: 'error',
  reporters: ['spec', ['allure', {
    outputDir: 'allure-results',
    disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
    disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
    useCucumberStepReporter:true,
  }]],

  framework: 'cucumber',
  cleanScreenshotsFolder: {
    screenshotPath: './test/reports/screenShots/currentRun',
    pattern: '/**/*'
  },
  hostname: 'selenium__standalone-chrome',
  port: 4444,
  path: '/wd/hub',
  services: [ [ 'selenium-standalone',{ drivers: { firefox: '0.29.1', chrome: 'latest', chromiumedge: 'latest' } } ], ],
  
  before: function () {
    i18n.configure({
      locales: ['en', 'es'],
      directory: 'test/locales',
      objectNotation: true
    });
    global.i18n = i18n;
    global.logger = require('winston');
  },

}, dynamicConfig);
```

package.json details are

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Automated BDD framework that uses webdriver.io, Node JS and cucumber-js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/projects/"
  },
  "main": "test/config/env/dev/dev.conf.js",
  "scripts": {
    
  },
  "keywords": [
    "test",
    "automation",
    "selenium",
    "webdriver",
    "webdriverIO"
  ],
  "author": "author",
  "license": "license",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "@cucumber/gherkin": "^25.0.2",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "await-to-js": "^3.0.0",
    "base64url": "3.0.0",
    "browserstack-local": "^1.4.3",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chromedriver": "^79.0.3",
    "commander": "2.15.1",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "custom-env": "^2.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "easy-yopmail": "^1.4.6",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "fibers": "^5.0.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "i18n": "0.8.3",
    "interval-promise": "1.2.0",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "newman": "^5.3.2",
    "node-html-parser": "1.1.10",
    "node-uuid": "1.4.7",
    "npm": "^6.14.16",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "4.2.2",
    "wait-until": "0.0.2",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "1.8.0",
    "webdriverio": "^5.11.0",
    "winston": "3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.8.0",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.22.4",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.16.10",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.11.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.11.0",
    "allure-commandline": "2.17.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "graphql": "^16.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "wdio-rerun-service": "^1.7.8"
  }
}
```

I am expecting the tests to pass successfully but I get the error every time

```
Execution of 1 spec files started at 2023-04-07T10:34:24.683Z
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /test/features/test.feature
[0-0] 2023-04-07T10:35:16.711Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.146)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (/builds/project/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:121:10)
    at Request._callback (/builds/project/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:121:64)
    at Request.self.callback (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/builds/project/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[0-0] Error in "Test: Test step: Given I navigate on the home screen"
unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.146)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this args to your capabilities

```
 args: [
      "window-size=1920,1080",
      "--disable-gpu",
      ...(process.env.CI_JOB_ID ? ["--headless"] : []),
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
    ],
```

Comment: as I couldn't find any solution, I ended up updating the project to the async mode and latest versions of used libraries. This particular error doesn't appear anymore however I have another error so cannot recommend it as solution